# NodeJs: executing a mongoshell with a js file of commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, shell

I wrote a nodeJS script that has a set of mongo commands. I ran it in the terminal using the following command and it worked:

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017 data.js
```

It worked, it performed all the operations that need to be done.

Afterwards, I created another nodeJS file, to automate this script. I executed the same command using the exec dependency.

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var execString = "mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017 " + config.file;
exec(execString, function(err, res){

    if (err) {
        return cb(err);
        console.log("here")
    }
    else
        console.log("Data import is Successfully Done");
    });
```

config.file contains the path to the js file. This is the error I received

```
{ Error: Command failed: mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017 /opt/soajs/node_modules/soajs.utilities/data/artifact/data.js

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:211:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:501:12)
killed: false,
code: 253,
signal: null,
cmd: 'mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017 /opt/soajs/node_modules.  /soajs.utilities/data/artifact/data.js' }
```

Comment: Have you compared the command in the first line of your error with the cmd in the last line? One is a path the other is two paths. Can you post the contents of config.file also?